# Show and Hide using buttons not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, show-hide

Alright I have been trying to fix this code and searching it up for more than like 6 hours and this is killing me

What I am trying to do is try to hide the login table and the background image associated with it (which is #lg #ck) and place a button on top of where the login table is so when it is clicked, it will show the login table

```
<?php

require_once( 'inc/header.inc.php' );

require_once( BX_DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'design.inc.php' );

require_once( BX_DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'db.inc.php' );

require_once( BX_DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'profiles.inc.php' );


check_logged();

if(!isMember()) {
echo '<body style="margin:0;">

<div style="margin:0 auto" align=center>

    <form onsubmit="validateLoginForm(this); return false;" method="post" action="member.php" id="login_box_form">

        <table id="ck">

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td width="180">Name</td>

                    <td width="150">Code</td>

                    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="180"><input style="width:180px;" name="ID" type="text"></td>

                    <td width="180"><input style="width:180px;"name="Password" type="password"></td>

                    <td><input name="LogIn" type="submit" tabindex="3" value="Login"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td width="180"><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"> Keep me logged in</td>

                    <td width="180"><a href="forgot.php">Forgot password?</a></td>

                    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </form>

</div>

<div style="width:100%;height:20px;clear:both;"></div>

<div style="width:100%;height:600px;padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;padding-top:20px;">';

}

else {
header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Nox's Ark</title>
</head>
<body id="lg"> <p class="bt"></p>
</div>
</p>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

html { 
  background: url(../img/bil.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow:hidden;

}
#ck {
    width:450px; 
    border: 5px; 
    align:center; 
    cellpadding= 0px; 
    cellspacing= 1px; 
    padding-left:1100px;
    padding-top:500px; 

    }
#lg {
    background-image:url(../img/nbt.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 1220px 380px;
    }
.bt {


</style>

</body>
</html>

<?php


?>
```

and here's the code someone suggested but I have no idea where to even place it.

```
<div id="ONE"><input type="button" value="Login" onClick="hideID('ONE');showID('TWO');" /></div>
<div id="TWO" style="display:none"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tr><td colspan="2"><h1>Login</h1></td></tr><tr><td>password:</td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr><tr><td>username:</td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="login" /></td></tr></table></div>
<script>
function hideID(objID){var element=(ie)?document.all(objID):document.getElementById(objID);element.style.display="none"}function showID(objID){var element=(ie)?document.all(objID):document.getElementById(objID);element.style.display="block"};
</script>
```

So I put

```
`<?php

require_once( 'inc/header.inc.php' );

require_once( BX_DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'design.inc.php' );

require_once( BX_DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'db.inc.php' );

require_once( BX_DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'profiles.inc.php' );


check_logged();

if(!isMember()) {
echo '<body style="margin:0;">

<div style="margin:0 auto" align=center>

    <form onsubmit="validateLoginForm(this); return false;" method="post" action="member.php" id="login_box_form">

        <table id="ck">

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td width="180">Name</td>

                    <td width="150">Code</td>

                    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="180"><input style="width:180px;" name="ID" type="text"></td>

                    <td width="180"><input style="width:180px;"name="Password" type="password"></td>

                    <td><input name="LogIn" type="submit" tabindex="3" value="Login"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td width="180"><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"> Keep me logged in</td>

                    <td width="180"><a href="forgot.php">Forgot password?</a></td>

                    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </form>

</div>

<div style="width:100%;height:20px;clear:both;"></div>

<div style="width:100%;height:600px;padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;padding-top:20px;">';

}

else {
header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Nox's Ark</title><div id="ONE"><input type="button" value="Login" onClick="hideID('ONE');showID('TWO');" /></div>
<div id="TWO" style="display:none"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tr><td colspan="2"><h1>Login</h1></td></tr><tr><td>password:</td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr><tr><td>username:</td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="login" /></td></tr></table></div><script>function hideID(objID) {
    var element = (ie) ? document.all(objID) : document.getElementById(objID);
    element.style.display = "none";
}

function showID(objID) {
    var element = (ie) ? document.all(objID) : document.getElementById(objID);
    element.style.display = "block";
}</script>
</head>
<body id="lg"> <p class="bt"></p>
</div>
</p>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

html { 
  background: url(../img/bil.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow:hidden;

}
#ck {
    width:450px; 
    border: 5px; 
    align:center; 
    cellpadding= 0px; 
    cellspacing= 1px; 
    padding-left:1100px;
    padding-top:500px; 

    }
#lg {
    background-image:url(../img/nbt.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 1220px 380px;
    }
.bt {


</style>

</body>
</html>

<?php


?>`
```

And this only shows a login button on left side and there's the previous login table on the right side (which I am trying to hide). The login button on left side doesn't do anything hen clicked.. 
I'd really
appreciate it if you guys could help me on this one, I don't even think I can do this by looking at tutorials.. SAVE ME ;_;

Comment: Please post your code, instead of drawing a smiley.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but what is happening currently?

Comment: There is nothing happening because when I place the code, a login box appears but does not do anything when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is the following:

```
<div id="ONE"><input type="button" value="Login" onClick="hideID('ONE');showID('TWO');" /></div>
<div id="TWO" style="display:none"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tr><td colspan="2"><h1>Login</h1></td></tr><tr><td>password:</td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr><tr><td>username:</td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="login" /></td></tr></table></div>
```

With JavaScript:

```
function hideID(objID) {
    var element = (ie) ? document.all(objID) : document.getElementById(objID);
    element.style.display = "none";
}

function showID(objID) {
    var element = (ie) ? document.all(objID) : document.getElementById(objID);
    element.style.display = "block";
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi! thanks for answring so fast :D !! but where do I put this?

Comment: <script>js</script> in <head> or any where,

Comment: I tried putting everything in the head but it only showed login button which didn't do anything. The previous login table is still there and nothing happens when I click it.